# Why did Wendy's house hang the French flag?

Tags: peter-pan

In Peter Pan (1953) Wendy's family seems to be a British family living in London. Why is there a French flag? I would have understood it if there were other flags like the UK flag, but there seems to be only the French flag.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may  be a reference to the Llewellyn Davies Boys who J.M. Barrie fostered. Their birth grandfather was the French-born cartoonist and writer George du Maurier.

Of course it could simply be a souvenir since the Darling's are upper class and are likely to have had the luxury of holidays across the English Channel.